# How to solve reverse DNS lookup error when mail.example.com is stored on server.example.com

Tags: postfix, reverse-dns

**Environment:** Digital Ocean, Centos 8, Postfix/Dovecot

**Background:** For my droplet I used a FQDN, `server.example.com`.  Digital Ocean configures the PTR record (reverse DNS entry) on their end based on the droplet name.

This works fine with my web server.  Unfortunately I'm getting a reverse DNS lookup error for my Postfix email server.  In Postfix `main.cf` I used `mail.server.com` as the value for the `myhostname` parameter. 
 Below are some relevant entries from my DNS records.

```
Type: A
Name: example.com
Value: 100.100.100.100

Type: A
Name: mail.example.com
Value: 100.100.100.100

Type: MX
Name: example.com
Value: mail.example.com
```

The error I get on MXToolbox is,

> Reverse DNS does not match SMTP Banner.

I tried adding an additional DNS record to fix the problem but the error didn't go away.

```
Type: A
Name: server.example.com
Value: 100.100.100.100
```

**Question:** Is there a DNS record I can add to fix this problem?  I'm not sure how to fix a reverse DNS lookup problem.

**Addendum**
The answer to this question is in the comments.  The correct way to solve this is to rename the mail server `server.example.com`.  Otherwise I would need 2 different Droplets or servers.  Email always comes from `user@example.com` so to end users their world looks the same regardless of what the mail server is named.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Only Digital Ocean can control the reverse DNS, as the `PTR` records aren't on your zone, but on an `in-addr.arpa.` zone controlled by the owner of the IP address. A Digital Ocean Community [question](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/questions/how-do-i-create-a-reverse-dns-ptr-record) has an answer to this:

> The Reverse DNS is configured automatically from our end based on the
>   droplet’s hostname.
>
> To rename your droplet via the control panel, do the following:
>
> 1. Login to the Digital Ocean Control Panel
> 2. Go to Droplets
> 3. --> Click the droplet you want to rename
> 4. Then, on the
>      droplet detail window, click on the name of your droplet (you wouldn’t
>      know you could)
> 5. Go to the Settings Tab
> 6. --> Change the name in the
>      entry field and click the check mark
>
> Make sure you also edit your droplet’s hostname internally as well.
>   Update `/etc/hostname` and `/etc/hosts` and reboot.
>
> The PTR should be automatically adjusted in few hours due to DNS
>   cache. If this is still not working after several hours, you can
>   contact our support team as well.

It's also possible to do the opposite i.e. alter your SMTP banner to match the current PTR record.

Comment: That would work but then the hostname for the server would be `mail.example.com`.  Is there no way for `mail.example.com` to be stored on `server.example.com` without a reverse DNS lookup problem?  I need two separate droplets?

Comment: No, you don't. Just change the SMTP banner to match the hostname.

Comment: That won't work because $myhostname is always appended to the start of the SMTP banner. myhostname is mail.example.com which always conflicts with server.example.com in PTR.

Comment: This is from the Postfix Doc.  `You MUST specify $myhostname at the start of the text. That is an # RFC requirement. `

Comment: That's why you change the `myhostname`.

Comment: I can do that.  But doesn't it seem weird that the server would be named `mail.example.com` when it's both a web and mail server?  Is that typical?

Comment: I changed the name of the web server to `server.example.com` and the error is gone.  So unless I want two droplets I guess that's the best way to solve this problem.  Mail always looks like it comes from `user@example.com` anyway.

Comment: HTTP doesn't care about the PTR: any web browser won't complain about a mismatch, and it's typical to have multiple sites on a single IP with virtual hosting. It wouldn't be against any standard not to have a matching PTR for SMTP, either. It's just that some mail systems might increase spam score based on that.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no A record you can add to fix this problem. You either need to somehow get the reverse DNS updated or change the name in the SMTP banner.

You can do this by setting the smtpd_banner directive in /etc/postfix.conf

Comment: See https://askubuntu.com/questions/1000455/reverse-dns-does-not-match-smtp-banner forthevsame question save for the Linux distro!

Comment: smtpd_banner directive can't fix it because $myhostname is always appended to the start of the banner.  myhostname is `mail.example.com` which always conflicts with `server.example.com` in PTR.

Comment: @MyNewAccount - did it occur to you you misunderstand what the man page says? It $myhostname was appended it would not be part of the customizeable string. You need a valid address. I challenge you to find an RFC that insists it needs to be the one you have in $myhostname - If you want to redo your postfix config, change $myhostname to server.example.com and modify the rest of the config to replace/augment $myhistname with mail.example.com

Comment: The docs are clear, `You MUST specify $myhostname at the start of the text. That is an
# RFC requirement.`  But I suppose I could rename `mail.example.com` to `server.example.com`.  I'm just surprised that's the way this is fixed.  It seems clunky.

Comment: @myNewAccount Please name the RFC. I am certain it does not exist (ive looked) and that $myhostname is a placeholder for the machine name. I expect you will only find an RFC that states the banner must start with the fqdn if the system ie section 4.3 of rfc821.

Comment: I only know what the Postfix documentation says.  BTW I just changed the mail server's name to `server.example.com` and the error is gone.  So I guess that's the easy solution.